# Read null DateTime from null list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm try to read Null dateTime from null List using Mvc5

```
List<TelecomPayments> telPayments = 
    db.TelecomPayments
        .Where(t => t.TelecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID == telecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID)
        .ToList();

telPayments.FirstOrDefault();
DateTime? lastDate = telPayments.FirstOrDefault().ToDate;

if (lastDate == null)
{
    if (telPayments.Count == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

this what I specify in controller but still through an expiation

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag should only be use for questions relating to the Visual Studio application, not code you create with it.

Comment: Can you specify the problem you've had with this code so that we don't have to guess?

Comment: what is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Unless I read something incorrectly - but if the list is null, you cannot do ToDate on a FirstOrDefault() as the Default will be null and thus throw a null pointer?

Comment: FYI This code is just C# + LINQ, so I removed the MVC tags.

Answer (score 1):

When using LINQ there are two groups of functions: those that return `IEnumerable<...>` (or `IQueryable<...>`), and those the return a `TResult`.

If you compose a LINQ statement, always make sure that all intermediate LINQ statements return `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`, only the last one may be `FirstOrDefault`, `ToList`, `Max`, `Any`, etc.

```
DateTime? lastDate = telPayments
    .Select(telpayment => telpayment.ToDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 6 or higher, then you can use the [**?.** aka "null conditional" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
List<TelecomPayments> telPayments = 
    db.TelecomPayments
        .Where(t => t.TelecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID == telecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID)
        .ToList();

DateTime? lastDate = telPayments.FirstOrDefault()?.ToDate;
```

This will only try to access **`.ToDate`** if the part before it is not null.

If you are on an older C# version then you will have to do a more explicit null check:

```
List<TelecomPayments> telPayments = 
    db.TelecomPayments
        .Where(t => t.TelecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID == telecomAdmin.TelecomAdminID)
        .ToList();

DateTime? lastDate = null;
var payment = telPayments.FirstOrDefault();
if (payment != null) lastDate = payment.ToDate;
```